# Is there any function to open .java/text file by clicking on button created in scenebuilder

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

So I have created two buttons in the scene builder
The first button is 'View chart' 
The second button is 'Generate Report'
However I am trying to find a way via the controller where I can open another .java file for the 'View chart' button and open a text file for 'Generate report' button

I have tried multiple Events etc

```
@FXML
private Button btnclick;
@FXML
private Button btnclick1;
```

the btnclick is for the 'View chart' button and btnclick1 is for the 'Generate report' button

Comment: Have you tried to learn any JavaFX basics?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean how to handle the button onAction event:

FXML:

```
<Button onAction="#onGenerateReportClicked" text="Generate report"/>
```

Controller class:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
...
...
public void onGenerateReportClicked(ActionEvent e){
    // Handle the event
}
```

Or:

FXML:

```
<Button fx:id="GenerateReport" text="Generate report"/>
```

Controller class:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Button GenerateReport;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        GenerateReport.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                // Handle the event
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh okay, I’ll have to try the onAction event. Just mainly want the two buttons to open a .java file/class and a text file

Comment: I recommend making the button name conform with java naming conventions, for example `generateReport`.